Is installing Ubuntu server and adding package *-desktop equivalent to installing *buntu Desktop?
current Ubuntu installation media (ubiquity , calamares) do have difficulties with manual partition and ecryption (luks + lvm), while the server installation (subiquity) works well.
Therefore:
If the 24.04 desktop installers can't be used for some forms of partition layout, is installing with the server installer and subsequently installing a *-desktop package equivalent to the regular desktops? Or are there any subtile differences?

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop doesn't use ubiquity, but uses the ubuntu-desktop-installer which is a front-end for subiquity (as used by Ubuntu Server). The ubiquity installer was last used with Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop as default for Ubuntu Desktop (though legacy ISOs with it were available for 23.04 & 23.10).

There are subtle differences set by the installed packages; eg. Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS defaults to the GA kernel stack, Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS defaults to the HWE kernel stack; Ubuntu flavors vary on ISO too (eg. Lubuntu 24.04 LTS using calamares will default to GA, but 24.04.2 will default to HWE)..   Differences though are minor, eg. kernel stack I'm using as example here.
